# What return type should void *function()s use?

Tags: c

Both of these tests don't give me errors when I compile them yet they are returning different types of pointers.

```
void    *testone(void *x)
{
  return (x);
}

void    *testtwo(void *x)
{
  char *y;
  return (y);
}
```

This is particularly confusing because I am trying to recreate the memcpy function and I can't tell if I should return a void pointer, or an unsigned char pointer.

Comment: `testtwo` is unsafe because it's returning an uninitialized value, not because of anything to do with the type.

Comment: You could avoid some minor problems with compilers by using `void *testtwo(void)` (to avoid 'unused parameter' warnings) and then initializing `y`.  However, those are nitpicks that are mostly tangential to your question, which is clear enough.

Comment: Void * generic pointer, in that case return type needs to be pointer of any type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, any object pointer type can be converted to `void *`, and `void *` can be converted to any object pointer type without any cast.

Your code obeys those rules; it is OK.  The compiler should not complain.

ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.3.2.3 Pointers:

> ¶1 A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

Note that 'object' excludes functions — function pointers have separate rules:

> ¶8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>   type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type,
>   the behavior is undefined.